# Checking if input meets the requirements before printing anything

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
input_list = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")

number = input_list.split()
if len(number) == 5:
    for n in number:
        a = int(n)
        if 0< a <=5:
            print 'x'* a
        elif a == 0:
            print '.'
        else:
            print "Number does not lie in the range 0 to 5."
else:
    print "Invalid Input."
```

I want my program to check if the 5 inputted numbers meets all the conditions and if even one them fails to print INVALID INPUT and stop the program. Also I don't quite understand how my program checks each inputted number on its own as my teacher helped me but didn't explain it . 
The program should ask for the number five times before printing anything
The program must check that the input are numbers are between 0 and 5.  It will also fail if a number of digits is entered other than 5.  Failed input can terminate the program with an appropriate error message.
Inputted numbers may be duplicates. (ex. 3, 3, 3, 0, 0 is acceptable input.)

Comment: Firstly, replace `input_list = raw_input...` by  `input_list = '1 3 5 66 89'`. You can add raw_input later, once you understand the rest. Then, try to debug it, or add `print n` statement just before `a = int(n)` to see what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Python's assert statement does:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> try:
...     assert(x==4)
... except(AssertionError):
...     print("Error!")
... 
>>> Error!
```

In the assert clause, you are stating a boolean condition which you are forcing to be true. If it is not true, you can catch the error using the except statement and handle it there.

In your case you could have:

```
assert(((x <= 5) and (x >= 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")
2   num_list = number.split()
3   for n in num_list:
4       a = 'True'
5       if int(n) <0 or int(n) >5:
6           a = 'False'
7           break       
8   if (len(num_list) == 5) and a == 'True':
9       for n in num_list:
10          b = int(n)
11          if 0< b <=5:
12              print ('x'* b)
13          elif b == 0:
14              print ('.')
15  else:
16      print 'Invalid Input!'
```